# Protractor cannot select element on overlay

Tags: protractor, overlay, element

I'm having trouble locating elements on an overlay. I've tried locating via by.id and it still doesn't find the element. I tried element(by.id('some-element'));

I'm not sure how this overlay is generated but it does go underneath a header menu on top of the page when you scroll. Not sure if that'll help any. Its not an iframe.

One more thing. Its a drupal app and specifically on the add user overlay. I think there something special going on there. Can someone see if they have the same issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, what if you add a `browser.sleep(5000)` right before locating an element of an overlay and doing actions on it? Any changes? (trying to see if this is a timing issue - if yes, there is a better way to handle it)

Comment: hi alecxe. I've tried that and even put in 10secs but no luck. I have a work around but it still does not solve why it can't locate elements in this overlay. This is the drupal url of the site http://my.site.com/stats/0#overlay=admin/people/create. Still investigating.

Comment: Sorry I just found its an iframe. <iframe class="overlay-element overlay-active" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" title="People dialog" frameborder="0">. How can we switch to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the overlay is inside an `iframe`, you first need to *switch to it's context*:

```
// wait for the frame to be present
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var iframe = $("iframe.overlay-active");
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(iframe), 5000);

// switch to the iframe
browser.switchTo().frame(iframe);

// do something

// get back to the main context
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: fixed, I used browser.switchTo().frame(1); Thanks.